# My delete button was working until I changed my mapping function

Tags: reactjs

So the delete button in my blog was working until I changed my code from this:

```
renderPosts(){
  const posts = this.state.posts;

  return _.map(posts, (post, key) => {
    return (
      <div key={key}>---BLOG POST---
        <button onClick={() => firebase.database().ref('posts').child(key).remove()}>Delete</button>

      </div>
    );
  }
  );
}
```

to this:

```
renderPosts(){
  const posts = this.state.posts;
  const sortedArray = _.orderBy(posts, ['timeStamp'], ['desc']);
  return _.map(sortedArray, (post, key) => {
    return (
      <div key={key}>---BLOG POST---
        <button onClick={() => firebase.database().ref('posts').child(key).remove()}>Delete</button>

      </div>
    );
  }
  );
}
```

I'm assuming it's because the onClick function no longer has access to the key as it's set in Firebase. How can I fix this so that state.posts is still ordered and so that my delete button works?

this.state.posts is an array

​

here's the repo if it's easier to read it all there:

https://github.com/C-H-I-L-L/crypto-info/blob/news-branch/src/components/blog/blog.js

Comment: What is the error you get in console?

Comment: What would be the key of the blog post? The key you currently use is the index in the array. Sorting the array changes the keys of the posts you use, but this is not in sync with firebase. Try accessing the key from the `post` variable instead

Comment: There are no errors in the console.

Comment: What do you mean accessing the key from the post variable instead? Do you mean replace key with post in the mapping function's div and onClick?